# Android - Sync HttpClient with your WebView session

Tags: android, httpclient, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making a hybrid application in android which uses webpages and native pages both. 
Now i have a web page which i open in my webview and then login through that page with some credentials.

I have another web service check_session.php which checks that if the session is maintained or not. I call that using HttpClient but that does not sync the session that i created on my webview. Even if I again login through web view it says you are already logged in.

How can we sync the session created on webview on my httpclient instance.

Please help.

Thanks